# Setting up SQL Server 2012 database mail to use SendGrid

Tags: sql-server-2012, smtp, sendgrid, database-mail

I have been trying all afternoon to get SQL Server 2012 **database mail** to use smtp.sendgrid.net to send email.

I just keep getting this error no matter what I try:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
>   Sending Mail using Account  Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. 
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or 
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I am running out of things to try. I am using my valid creds from SendGrid and I can confirm these work.

I am using port 25 but have tried all other suggested ports from SendGrid documentation.

Does anyone have any tips they can give me?

Thanks

Russ

Comment: Russ, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @JimKiely I never got it to work. Wasn't a priority. Sorry i'm not more help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working SQL Server 2012 Mail + SendGrid setup:

```
Server name:  smtp.sendgrid.net
Port:         587
Use SSL?      No

Use Basic Authentication with your SendGrid user/pass
```

SendGrid apparently doesn't support port 25 any longer, and TLS on port 465 isn't an (easy) option for SQL Mail.

Comment: Where did you learn to use Port 587 instead of the default 25?